# What was the word translated as "Kamikaze" in the subtitled version of “Godzilla: Minus One?”

Tags: translation, subtitles, godzilla-minus-one

In the movie *Godzilla: Minus One* (2023) the English language subtitles use the word Kamikaze multiple times throughout its runtime, but in several scenes the Japanese language dialog uses a different word.

For example, in the subtitles, while preparing the aircraft for the final showdown, Tachibana describes Shikishima as being a "former Kamikaze", but his Japanese language dialog uses an alternative word. From a grammatical perspective, the word appears in the exact sentence position that you would expect to hear Kamikaze.

Does anybody know what the meaning of this word is, or how it is written in Kanji?

I cannot remember it's pronunciation.

Comment: Haven't seen it and had to look this up under kamikaze as it escaped my memory: they were officially called special attack units or "tokubetsu kōgekitai." Is this closer to what you heard?

Comment: @Yorik This could well be it, or close to it. I only remember it being a single word though so it might be a shortening.

Comment: Wikipedia - *"This is usually abbreviated to tokkōtai (特攻隊). "*

Comment: @Paulie_D, BINGO, I'm sure that this is it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Wikipedia the *Kamikaze* were officially called special attack units or *"tokubetsu kōgekitai."* but this is usually abbreviated to ***"tokkōtai (特攻隊)."***

This is the word used.